# How can erase first character of all string in file

Tags: sed, awk

How can erase first character of all string in file if this is zero?

e.g

I have file

```
$ cat file

01111111  01222222 6666066
09999011  02222044 0743333
01000000  30000000 2222220
```

Try with sed command output:

```
$ sed 's/^0*\(.*\)/\1/' file

1111111  01222222 6666066
9999011  02222044 0743333
1000000  30000000 2222220
```

but this only erase the zero in the first column.

How to erase all zeros in first character in file e.g output:

```
1111111   1222222 6666066
9999011   2222044  743333
1000000  30000000 2222220
```

Comment: What if the string is `007`? What if it's `000`? What if it's `0`?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably fair to assume that a string in your text is delimited by white space. If so, you need to remove a zero whenever it is preceded by white space:

```
sed 's/\([[:space:]]\)0/\1/g'
```

The `\(...\)` construct saves the white space that precedes a zero, and the `\1` in the replacement recalls the saved text.

Then take care of leading zeroes as well:

```
sed -e 's/\([[:space:]]\)0/\1/g' -e 's/^0//'
```

By the way, your example does not **erase** the non-initial zeroes, but it **replaces** them with a blank. My solution assumes erasure.

Also, you solution for replacing the leading zero actually replaces a whole sequence of leading zeros. However, your question asks for the **first** zero to be erased. That's what my solution does.

Comment: thanks friend great idea maybe is best remplace with blank  left zeros, so the output form 1111111  1222222 6666066
9999011  2222044 743333
1000000  30000000 2222220

Comment: To replace the leading zero with a space, modify the sed call like this: `sed -e 's/\([[:space:]]\)0/\1 /g' -e 's/^0/ /'`.

Answer (score 0):

Perl is handy for this:

```bsh
perl -lape 's/\b(0+)/" " x length($1)/ge' file
```

```
 1111111   1222222 6666066
 9999011   2222044  743333
 1000000  30000000 2222220
```

Or, the equivalent in awk

```bsh
awk '{while (1) if (gsub(/\<0/, " ", $0) == 0) break; print}' file
```

Both of those will turn "0" or "00" (as standalone words) into just spaces.

If you have

```bsh
$ cat file
01111111  01222222 6666066
09999011  02222044 0743333
01000000  30000000 2222220
00000007  00000009 0000000
```

Then to preserve the zero values in the last line, you can:

```bsh
$ perl -lape 's/\b(0+)(\d)/" " x length($1) . $2/ge' file
 1111111   1222222 6666066
 9999011   2222044  743333
 1000000  30000000 2222220
       7         9       0
```